# Lombok (Builder) Object to Protobuf object

Tags: java, mapstruct, modelmapper, protobuf-java

I created a POJO using lombok/auto-value with builder pattern. I need to convert the object into a java model which is generated by protobuf.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        User user = User.builder()
                .userName("username")
                .userId(1)
                .build();

//      Protouser.ProtoUser protoUser = Protouser.ProtoUser
//              .newBuilder()
//              .setUserName("usernmae")
//              .setUserId(1)
//              .build();
    }
}

@Getter
@ToString
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
class User {
    @NonNull
    private String userName;

    private int userId;
}
```

Protobuf file

```
syntax = "proto3";
message ProtoUser {
    string userName = 1;
    int32 userId = 2;
}
```

I am trying to use the following libraries to achieve this but failing.

- [mapstruct - 1.3.0.beta 1](http://mapstruct.org/news/2018-07-15-mapstruct-1_3_0_Beta1-is-out-with-builder-support/)
- [Model-mapper](https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/tree/master/extensions/protobuf)
- [Simpleflatmapper](http://simpleflatmapper.org/0204-protobuf.html)

Can anyone help me with this or Is there is any other library to do this conversion or handle it in better way?

Comment: I think it should work to map object to protocol buffer builder: https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/blob/master/extensions/protobuf/src/test/java/org/modelmapper/protobuf/ProtobufModuleTest.java#L36-L58.

Comment: I was able to achieve this using mapstruct

Comment: SimpleFlatMapper does not do object to object mapping so won't be useful for that case.

Comment: @suraj1291993 can you please show example, how you achieved it?

Comment: @AnatoliiStepaniuk I used https://github.com/entur/mapstruct-spi-protobuf to achieve it. Currently I dont have any sample implementation.

Comment: @AnatoliiStepaniuk for some reason, after i integrate github.com/entur/mapstruct-spi-protobuf get an error saying error: Couldn't retrieve Mapper annotation

Answer (score -2):

You can use translator to do this:

```
public User translate(native) {
        return User.builder()
        .userName(native.getUserName())
        .userID(native.getUserID())
        .build();
 }
```

Here `native` is a builder for User Message or you can the STUB.